# Product of a projective variety and a pseudo-projective variety/ birational

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am getting really confused in trying to solve the following exercise :

"Let $\mathbb{K}$ be an algebraically closed field, $X \subset \mathbb{P}^n$ be a projective variety over $\mathbb{K}$ and $W \subset \mathbb{P}^{m}$ be a quasi-projective variety over $\mathbb{K}$. Construct a $\mathbb{K}$-algebra isomorphism between $\mathcal{O}(X \times W)$ and $\mathcal{O}(W)$ (where $\mathcal{O}(Y)$ denotes the ring of regular functions at every point of $Y$).
Hint : Consider regular functions as morphisms to $\mathbb{A}^{1}$."

The simplest way of proceeding is probably to consider the pullback:

\begin{alignat*}{4}
\pi^{*} : \: &  \mathcal{O} (W)  \: & \rightarrow \: & \mathcal{O}(X \times W) \\
         \: & f  \: &  \mapsto     \: &  f\circ \pi,
\end{alignat*}
for $\pi : X \times W \rightarrow W$ the canonical projection, and to show that it is the desired isomorphism of $\mathbb{K}$-algebras. We only have to check that $\pi^{*}$ is indeed a bijective the other verifications being clear. The injectivity follows directly from the surjectivity of $\pi$, but I fail in showing the surjectivity. For a given map $f \in \mathcal{O}(X \times W)$ I though to construct explicitely a rational map $\tilde{f}$ over $\mathcal{O}(W)$ such that $\tilde{f}\circ \pi = f$. Given $w \in W$ the preimage of $\{w\}$ is closed in $X \times W$ and thus defined as the zero set of polynomials $f_1, \cdots, f_d \in \mathbb{K}[x_1, \cdots, x_{n+m+nm}]$, I have tried to play with that but it doesn't lead to anything.

I think that somewhere I will have to use that since $X$ is projective the projection on the second component is closed...

Please help I really don't know how to deal with that!

By the way I also failed in finding an example showing why the statement becomes false when not considering $X$ projective anymore.

Any kind of help would be most appreciated!

Comment: If $X\times W\to\mathbb{A}^1$ is a morphism, what happens when you restrict it to say $X\times \{w\}$ for a point $w\in W$?

Comment: Obviously, for the statement to hold true, $X$ has to be connected. That said, and taking that as a given... Are you OK with @Mohan's comment/suggestion? To see that the statement can fail if $X$ is not projective, take $X= W = \mathbb A^1$.

Comment: Many thanks for answering so quickly! I have tried to work with your suggestions but I am still completely confused, I am probably missing an important point. So if $f : X \times W \rightarrow \mathbb{A}^{1}$ is a morphism, and take $w \in W$.  If I restrict f to $X \times \{w\}$ since $f$ is a morphism I know (do I? I mean is $f(X\times \{w\})$ open in $\mathbb{A}^{1}$?) that for any $\phi : f(X \times \{w\}) \rightarrow \mathbb{A}^{1}$, $\phi \circ f$ will be regular over $X \times \{w\}$. But I still don't see the point...

Comment: The point of @Mohan's suggestion is that if $X$ is projective (and connected - but is that part of your definition?), then any $\mathbb K$-morphism $X \rightarrow \mathbb A^1$ is constant - i.e., that ${\mathcal O}(X)= \mathbb K$ - for reference: https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~osserman/classes/248A-F13/6-projective.pdf prop 3.7. Does this help?

Comment: Oops, sorry, the reference shows that the statement holds for $X$ complete, but does not show that projective varieties are complete. Do you know the statement?

Comment: Prop 7.18 to Cor 7.25 of http://www.mathematik.uni-kl.de/~gathmann/class/alggeom-2014/chapter-7.pdf is a complete (ha-ha) proof  for projective varieties. This is a classical proof. For an entirely  different style of argument, see Hartshorne's AG, prop 4.9

Comment: Things start to be clear, thanks a lot! Just to be sure: let $f \in \mathbb{O}(X\times W)$, we seek $\tilde{f} \in \mathcal{O}(W)$ such that $\tilde{f}\circ \pi = f$. Since $X$ is complete $f$ is constant over the preimage of $w\in W$ (its restriction to $X\times \{w\}$ is regular and in bijective correspondance with regular functions over $X$ (to $f \in \mathcal{O}(X \times \{w\})$ corresponds $\tilde{f}\in \mathcal{O}(X)$ s.t $\tilde{f}(x)=f(x,w)$ and reciprocally any $f\in \mathcal{O}(X)$ can be seen as an element of $\mathcal{O}(X\times \{w\})$). This allows us to define $\tilde{f}$.

Comment: I would say, if you  fix $x_0\in X$, you have a map $r\colon{\mathcal O}(X\times W) \rightarrow \mathcal O (W)$: $$f\mapsto f|_{x_0\times W}.$$ Since $f(x,w) = f( x_0,w)$ for all $x\in X$ , as  $f$ is constant on $X \times \{w\}$, the map $r$ is the inverse of your map $\pi^*$ (and does not depend on the choice of $x_0$).